# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a function that brings me to the error:

> `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()`

I can't understand why it is throwing

```
public function multiplelinkPlayerWithFamily($parent_id)
{
    $player_id = Input::get('player_id');
    $CheckRelationship = UsersRelationship::where('parent_user_id', $parent_id)->where('child_user_id', $player_id)->first();

    if($CheckRelationship) {
        return Response::json( [
            'ok'=> false,
            'message'=> 'The profiles are currently linked '
        ] ,422);
    }

    $user = User::find($player_id);

    $user->parent_id = $parent_id;
    $user->updated_by = $parent_id;

    $user->save();

    $UsersRelationship = new UsersRelationship;

    $UsersRelationship->parent_user_id = $parent_id;
    $UsersRelationship->child_user_id = $player_id;

    $UsersRelationship->save();

    $udata = ApiUserController::getLoginUserData();

    return Response::json([
        'ok'=> true,
        'message'=> 'Linked',
        'udata'=> $udata
    ] ,200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how your models are structured, but it looks like you've actually turned a model into a relation: ie. `$UsersRelationship`
It looks like you're trying to set up a many-to-many relation between users, correct?

```
public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','users_relationships','child_id','parent_id');
}

 public function children()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','users_relationships','parent_id','child_id');
 }
```

Once you've got the relations set up right, you can call:

```
$user->parents()->attach($parent_id);
```

Comment: Hard to say from your code, as I can't see how you've set up your relations, but getting that right can go a long way...

Comment: nothing happnd Cloete i don't understand whats the meaning of that error

Comment: Show us the code from your class `UsersRelationship`

Comment: class UsersRelationship extends Eloquent  
{


 protected $table = 'users_relationships';

 public $primaryKey = 'id';

 protected $hidden = array();

 protected $guarded = array();

 protected $fillable = array();

Comment: Looks good. Are you using laravel 4.2? If so, i recommend to switch to laravel 5.1 for long-term support. Also: please watch the laravel fundamentals at: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals It will help you with many of the basic stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I think your users_relationships shouldn't be a model in of itself. You shoudl set up the relations in the User model. But if you really want to use the UsersRelationship as a model, you should add 'parent_user_id' and 'child_user_id' to your fillable array..

Answer (score 1):

All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent, either via the get method or a relationship, will return a collection object. If the result of your query is likely to return more than one value, Laravel returns a collection. Understanding query methods that returns a Collection would save you the problem of calling an Eloquent model method on a Collection.

Your query is most likely to return more than one record from the database or none from the database. This would cause 'Eloquent' to return a Collection even if the number of records found is One. Because the the returned value is a Collection, we would need to loop through the returned set to have access to the individual Model.

So try replace your below code:

```
$user = User::find($player_id);

$user->parent_id = $parent_id;
$user->updated_by = $parent_id;
$user->save();
```

and replace it as like given below:

```
$user = User::find($player_id);
$user->each(function($user)
{
    $user->parent_id = $parent_id;
    $user->updated_by = $parent_id;
    $user->save();
});
```

Hope it may work.

Comment: you can also use simple foreach looping method also to loop through the returned set to have access to the individual model.

Comment: like: foreach($user as $user) { 
           $user->parent_id = $parent_id;
           $user->updated_by = $parent_id;
           $user->save();     
       }